# Why does it take different amounts of time for Neo4j to delete a whole databse?

Tags: neo4j, match

I work with a large database that I am using to determine the shortest path in a graph database. When I set few relationships or nodes that are not correct, I tend to delete to database in a single command and correct. I have encountered an interesting phenomenon, that the classic command to do this... :

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

...take different amounts of time to commit it. 4/5 cases, it does not commit at all and I would like to know why. I am working with 9000 nodes, I think this a reasonably small number to be worried (Neo4j should be able to handle 100000+ nodes with ease)

Comment: please provide more information, OS, heap settings, pagecache, neo4j version, ...

Answer (score 2):

Depends also on the number of relationships and properties that you are deleting.
As Neo4 is a transactional databases it has to keep the intermediate state until the tx commits in memory.

You are faster off by deleting the graph.db directory and starting the server again.

otherwise you can batch it like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
RETURN count(*);
```

until it returns 0